# Change 'Categories' to 'Topics'

Tags: functions, translation

[image: How can one change this to 'Topics'?]

I'm trying to find a way of displaying 'Topics' rather than 'Categories' and  so far not being very successful.

I tried this:

```
function translate_category($translated) { 


$translated = str_ireplace('Category', 'Topic', $translated);
  return $translated; 
}

function translate_categories($translated) { 
  $translated = str_ireplace('Categories', 'Topics', $translated);
  return $translated; 
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: not clear question for me

Comment: I added a screenshot tomato the question clearer.

Comment: this meta box heading?

Comment: function replace_text($text) {
 $text1 = str_replace('Category', 'Topic', $text1);
 $text2 = str_replace('Categories', 'Topics', $text2);
 return $text;
}
add_filter('int', 'replace_text');

Comment: add this function.php file

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do the trick either.

Comment: where does the 'categories' text come from? a widget? your theme?

Comment: They're the theme categories.

Answer (score 0):

Changing category base prefix is quite simple in WordPress.

You need to visit Settings » Permalinks page and scroll down to the ‘Optional’ section.

[image: changing category base prefix]

Comment: That only changes the slug, not the name.  'Categories' will continue to appear as the description even if you rename the slug to 'topics'.

Comment: you must edit theme and find place this code and change word of Categories